# Error produced from mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently learning MySql, but ive hit this problem.
the following code should just query the db for everything in the users table. but it returns this error. `Error: SELECT * FROM users` which helps me not at all. I am able to successfully insert an item into the database, but I am unable to select from it. I've also tried `$sql = "SELECT * FROM ama.users";` my DB structure is

```
 ama
 |-users
```

any help would be much appreciated.

```
  $conn = new mysqli($_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'],$_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'], $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'], 'ama');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$username = "Doe";
$password = "johnexample";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: please add the complete error message

Comment: @Jens that is the complete error message it gives me.. if it gave more id be able to debug better.

Comment: Doing === TRUE won't work on a select, because it returns a resource object or null. So == TRUE should work though. === is a strict type check, which means it must be a boolean, and a resource object is not a boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):**

mysqli::query will return object in success and return false in failure.

So you can use it without checking data type (===):

```
if ($conn->query($sql)) { 
     echo "New record created successfully"; 
} else { 
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
}
```

For more better understanding you can use `var_dump()` and check what are you getting like:

```
var_dump($conn->query($sql));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) says:

Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So, do something like

```
$result= $db->query($sql);
```

and then check the rows in $result